# Timeout error when listing S3 buckets using erlcloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, erlang, elixir

I'm trying to use the [erlcloud](https://github.com/gleber/erlcloud) library for S3 uploads in my app. As a test, I'm trying to get it to list buckets via an `iex` console:

```
iex(4)> s3 = :erlcloud_s3.new("KEY_ID", "SECRET_KEY")
...
iex(5)> :erlcloud_s3.list_buckets(s3)
** (ErlangError) erlang error: {:aws_error, {:socket_error, :timeout}}
    (erlcloud) src/erlcloud_s3.erl:909: :erlcloud_s3.s3_request/8
    (erlcloud) src/erlcloud_s3.erl:893: :erlcloud_s3.s3_xml_request/8
    (erlcloud) src/erlcloud_s3.erl:238: :erlcloud_s3.list_buckets/1
```

I've checked that `inets`, `ssl`, and `erlcoud` are all started, and I know the credentials work fine, because I've tested them in a similar fashion with a Ruby library in `irb`.

I've tried configuring it with a longer timeout, but no matter how high I set it I still get  this error.

Any ideas? Or approaches I could take to debug this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could simulate the same error, and could resolve it by replacing double-quote with single-quote.

```
> iex(4)> s3 = :erlcloud_s3.new('KEY_ID', 'SECRET_KEY')
> iex(5)> :erlcloud_s3.list_buckets(s3)
```

Assuming the double-quote was used, it may be caused by a type mismatch between string and char-list.

Comment: Ok, that has just taken the award for the worst error message I've ever seen. Thanks :) How did you even think to try that?

Comment: In general when dealing with Erlang libs, pass "strings" single quoted. I say _strings_ exactly because single quote passes a char list and double quote passes a string and you usually want to pass a char list to Erlang.

Comment: As indicated above, single quote would be usually applied when using erlang libs. In this case, the same API was working with default config (which acquires the key and secret from environment variables) in my environment previously. Then I could track down the difference between this error scenario and previous working one.